# How to check if a file exists?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a method that write a txt plain file on the external memory..

And it works! .. but i want to insert the Date of creation on the footer of the file thorugh the file.exists() method.

If exists doesn't insert date and if not exists insert the date..

My code is this..

```
File idea=new File(dir,titulo+".txt");
            FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(idea);
            if (!(idea.exists())){
                texto.append("\n\n\tCreada :"+new Fecha().toString());
            }
```

Supposing that dir is my path..

```
    File dir =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/CMI");
```

and titulo is a parameter that the metod get when is called .. and contains the filename.

(Fecha it's my Date class that returns a Date as String)

Comment: `if(!idea.exists())` without brackets that surround the statement

Comment: consider adding a java tag to this question.. this belongs to java totally.. and you will get satisfactory answers..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File idea=new File(dir,titulo+".txt");
if (!idea.exists()){
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(idea);
    texto.append("\n\n\tCreada :" + new Fecha().toString());
    return;
}
```

Try the above code. If you say `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(idea);` it creates a new file if it doesn't exist. So the `exist()` method doesn't make any difference and always returns true.

Answer (score 2):

can you just mould the code

```java
File idea = new File(dir, titulo + ".txt");

if (idea.exists()){
    //do nothing
}
else {
    FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(idea);
    texto.append("\n\n\tCreada :" + new Fecha().toString());
}
```

Comment: Yep that solution requires more code, switching the code as ntc said worked..

Thanks :)

Comment: even if it is more code, its a better practice to consider always an else statement, even if it is empty, just comment why it is empty (using @ntc answer)

Comment: well i just tried to provide him a clue not the whole answer.. and if it has return statement why do u need an else statement to do nothing.. it just makes it more readable and does't change one's implementation.

Comment: and plz consider it as healthy discussion and not a debate.. even i don't have ample experience in coding..

Comment: @ntc I dont know if that comment was for me but Im not saying anything about your answer, it is perfect!, Im just sharing my experience _(**"using your answer"** means, just add that and it will be GREAT!)_ :)

Comment: yup i got i .. and it was just a clarification and again i'm not saying anything u said is wrong..:)